# Solution check of an exponential equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, exponential-function

I'm solving an exponential equation and I would like to check my solution with someone. The result should be $x=1$ which is what I get, but I'm not sure if my math is correct.

$$2^x + 2^{x+1} = -2^{x-1}+7 $$
$$2^x *1 + 2^{x}*2 = -2^{x}:2+7 $$
$$2^x *(1 + 2) = -2^{x}:2+7 $$
$$2^x(3) = -2^{x}:2+7 $$
$$2^x(3) + 2^{x}:2 = +7 $$
Dividing $2$ by $2$ is just multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$
$$2^x(3) + 2^{x}* \frac{1}{2} = +7 $$
$$2^x(3 +\frac{1}{2}) = +7 $$
$$2^x(\frac{7}{2}) = +7^1 $$

Now since I have only two exponents (the x and the 1 belonging to the 7) I can equate them 
$$x=1$$

Is this correct?

Edit: I'm just seeing this.

$$2^1(\frac{7}{2}) = +7^1 $$
$$2(\frac{7}{2}) = +7 $$

Simplify 2 and $\frac{7}{2}$

$$7 = 7 $$

I think this is correct then? It is 2am here, sorry if this is very obvious haha

Comment: What does : 2 + 7 mean?

Comment: $ -2^{x-1}+7$ turns into $(-2^{x}:2)+7 $

Comment: What does : mean?

Comment: Divided, like $/$, the division symbol

Comment: Then why not use / the division symbol?

Answer (score 1):

You can only equate the exponents if the bases are equal.

Here is another approach:
\begin{align*}
2^x + 2^{x + 1} & = -2^{x - 1} + 7\\
2^{x + 1} + 2^x + 2^{x - 1} & = 7\\
2^{x - 1}(2^2 + 2 + 1) & = 7\\
2^{x - 1}(4 + 2 + 1) & = 7\\
2^{x - 1} \cdot 7 & = 7\\
2^{x - 1} & = 1\\
2^{x - 1} & = 2^0
\end{align*}
Since the bases are equal, we can equate the exponents.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
x - 1 & = 0\\
x & = 1
\end{align*}

Everything you did was correct until you reached the step
$$2^x\left(\frac{7}{2}\right) = 7$$
If you multiply both sides of this equation by $\dfrac{2}{7}$, you obtain
\begin{align*}
2^x & = 2\\
2^x & = 2^1
\end{align*}
Since the bases are the same, we may equate the exponents, which yields
$$x = 1$$
as above.

What you cannot do is equate the exponent of the $2$ and the exponent of the $7$.  You obtained the correct answer for the wrong reason.  To see why, suppose you had 
$$2^x = 8^1$$
By your reasoning, $x = 1$.  However, $8 = 2^3$.  Hence, what we should obtain is
$$2^x = 2^3$$
Since the bases are the same, we can equate the exponents, which yields $x = 3$, not $x = 1$.